# P2S connections with Azure Express Route

Tags: azure, networking, vpn

A question regarding P2S and Express Route connectivity co-existence in same virtual gateway. At Azure portal, there is an option to configure P2S connections to virtual gateway that is Express Route gateway type. But generally, when setting up VPN (S2S) and ER co-existence, MSFT recommends that separate virtual GW is built for VPN GW. MSFT documentation only talks about S2S and ER co-existence in vNet, nothing about P2S and ER.

So my questions are, does P2S connections work if you setup those to ER VGW? And does anyone know, what is MSFT recommended best practice in this scenario?

Comment: Just for clarification, you're asking if ER supports P2S connections in general? Or are you asking how to configure P2S with a VPN gateway in a coexistance scenario where you have an Express Route gateway and a VPN gateway in the same Vnet?

Comment: As ER GW seems to have option to configure P2S connections (would add screenshot from portal, but not enough XP), I'm asking can P2S connections co-exist with ER connection at virtual GW that is type ER. As I wrote I know VPN and ER GW's can co-exist, but is there actually need for separate VPN GW if one already has ER GW as Azure provides option to configure P2S connection to same GW as ER.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any P2S support within the ExpressRoute Gateway.  The ExpressRoute circuits are essentially virtual leased lines, and the configuration for ExpressRoute is about circuits, connections, ports, routing.

The VPN Gateways do support both S2S and P2S.  You can also effectively combine VPN and ExpressRoute Gateways, so if you want belt and braces you can have a S2S VPN connection traverse the ExpressRoute link so it will be encrypted as well as private.

If there is an option for P2S in your ExpressRoute perhaps you could screenshot it and paste it in here? I can see nothing for it in the documentation or in the ARM template reference area.

Comment: Hi Richard,
That was my understanding previously too. But as Azure portal seems to provide option to setup P2S connections to virtual GW that is type ER, just wondering, is there actually a need for separeate VPN GW is one wants P2S and ER connections co-exist in same vNet. Cannot add screenshots as I don't have enough xp.

Comment: Have you tried running the configuration for P2S? It more than likely will fail with some sort of invalid gateway type. Checking further to confirm this :D

Answer (score 0):

ExpressRoute gateways are not *supposed* to show the option of adding P2S configuration. You would need to configure a coexistent VPN GW that has P2S configured. If you're still seeing this option on your ExR GW, that's likely a bug.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-howto-coexist-resource-manager#to-add-point-to-site-configuration-to-the-vpn-gateway